# This Foreach Loop Proceeds All $_POST Input, How To Make It More Specific?

Tags: php

I have this code on HTML side :

```
<form action="testx.php" method="post">
<input type="hidden" name="block-1" value="001"/>
<input type="hidden" name="block-2" value="012"/>
<input type="hidden" name="block-3" value="002"/>
<input type="hidden" name="block-4" value="005"/>
<input type="hidden" name="block-5" value="008"/>

<input type="hidden" name="title" value="title goes here"/>
<input type="hidden" name="code" value="018439128484"/>
<input type="submit" value="Finish!" class="submit-btn" />
</form>
```

and I have this Foreach loop on PHP side :

```
<?php
$i=0;
foreach($_POST as $name => $value)
{
   echo $i . " - " . $name . ": " . $value . "<br>";
   $i++;
}  
?>
```

unfortunately, that Foreach loop proceeds all inputs... how to make that this loop ONLY proceeds inputs with name "block-X" ?

I tried to give a try like this, but failed :

```
$i=0;
$x = 'block-'.$i+1;
foreach($_POST[$x] as $name => $value)
```

it says : **Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach()**

thanks!

Comment: This is the exact code that I provided you in response to your previous question, and I gave you the answer to this exact question in that same answer! Read it! Else what's the point asking for my help in the comment...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try filtering by `$name` inside the loop, for instance with [`strpos`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php):

```
<?php
$i=0;
foreach($_POST as $name => $value)
{
   if(strpos($name, 'block-')===0) {
      echo $i . " - " . $name . ": " . $value . "<br>";
      $i++;
   }
}  
?>
```

Comment: No. By looping over the actual relevant keys. Looping over every key and filtering out the ones you don't want is the most ass-backwards way of doing this.

Comment: Can you be more specific: in which way it is "the most ass-backwards way of doing this"? Assuming his requirement is "that given we don't know what keys are present in `$_POST`, choose those that start with `block-`", you don't have any other options than to iterate through the whole array. Well yeah, you could use `array_filter`, `substr` or some other function as well, but it doesn't change the idea. Obvious I'm extrapolating from his example and assuming that he wants the script to work with other kind of forms as well - so yes, I did use some healthy *common sense* as well.

Answer (score 2):

The only way i see right now is:

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $value)
{
   if(substr($name, 0, 5) == "block"){
    echo $i . " - " . $name . ": " . $value . "<br>";
    $i++;
  }
}
```

Edit: Someone is faster than me :x

Another solution, that would avoid a string comparison

```
while(isset($_POST["block-".$i])){
  echo $i . " - block-" . $i . ": " . $_POST["block-".$i] . "<br>";
  $i++;
}
```

Comment: In SO there is an axiom: "Speed of typing is faster than the speed of light" ;)

Comment: RegExps not substr and never concat on echo. Don't . elements but , them for performance... echo is a language construct and gets special treatment.

Answer (score 1):

All other answers are wrong.

You have 5 specific indicies you are interested in. They are numeric and sequential. You want to iterate from 1 to 5. You do *not* want to iterate over the entire `$_POST` array, selectively skipping keys, and you **absolutely** do not want to involve regular expressions in such a trivial task. Every answer which uses regular expressions to solve this is flat out wrong and the ones that use `strpos` are not much better.

Use this:

```
for ($i = 1; $i <= 5; ++$i) {
   echo "$i = block-$i: ", $_POST["block-$i"];
}
```

Comment: Except that he said 'how to make that this loop ONLY proceeds inputs with name "block-X"'. It means it should work even if you add another block-X item. Else he would say "proceeds inputs with name block-1 to block-5".

Comment: "All other answers are wrong" this is a heavy thing to say. You could just rephrase it to "There can be a simpler approach to follow"...

Comment: No. When you introduce such a crazy level of complexity to your answer when traditional `for` loop is the solution, you are *doing it wrong*. This is not a subjective thing. It is *objectively* wrong to use regular expressions or `strpos` for this problem.

Comment: Hey pal, your solution is completely different than others. You're right, by having IF inside the loop, means my script will do 'double checking' for every loop. Resource consuming... But my question is, regarding your solution, how to get the '5' in this line : $i <= 5;. Because, in the real world, it's not 5. It's dynamic. Can be 2, 9, 11, 4, etc.

Comment: You need to know how many there are. If you don't know how many, my solution can't work and the other solutions *are* better. This is why clarity is important.