# Need syntax help using foreach() in an effort to post inputs

Tags: php, forms, post, for-loop, foreach

I am obviously a novice coder, & I have been reading various posts trying to accomplish the following:

I have a form which contains a multitude of `<textarea>` input fields, 150 rows and three columns ( The reason they are `<textarea>`'s is related to a special javaScript functionality that I shan't go into detail with, but it has the have to be `<textarea>` ).

Here is a capture of how it looks ( but all the way to 150 ):

[image: form capture in browser]

I am posting the form to another page, PHP of course, where I want to do three things:

**1)** Display a summary of certain parameters ( date of submission, sums, counts, etc.)

**2)** Assign variables consistent with all the 450 total inputs using loops in some fashion

**3)** Create, Save and create a link for the user to download a CSV file with the data.

Step 1) if pretty much done, no dramas there

Step 3) I am pretty sure that I can work out, as there are many good tutorials out there for writing files with php.

Step 2) is where I am at a loss.

**It is also important to note:**

**A)** Not all rows need to be filled in when submitting the form; although an individual row needs to be completed

**B)** The 'posting' (right word?) in the loop need to be limited to only the max number of completed rows. So I don't think a straight `for()` loop will work as it will return all 150 rows even if blank.

I have been playing with a bit of code I found on a post here using `foreach()`, from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12973852/this-foreach-loop-proceeds-all-post-input-how-to-make-it-more-specific).

Here is a code I Frankenstein'ed together, it returns ok (only for the first column {let's call it column_A} and it is limited by the number of filled fields using the column_A as a ruler.

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $inputA) {

    if(strpos($name, 'column_A')===0) {
        if($inputA !== ''){
            echo $i , " )" , " " , $inputA , "<br />";
            $i++;
        }
    }
}
```

So if I fill in 5 rows, with some data, then this code will return:

1) *column A one*

2) *column A two*

3) *column A three*

4) *column A four*

5) *column A five*

But I also need to echo also column_B and column_C along side the column_A. as en example:

1) *column A one* , *column B one* , *column C one*

2) *column A two* , *column B two* , *column C two*

3) *column A three* , *column B three*  , *column C three*

4) *column A four* , *column B four* , *column C four*

5) *column A five* , *column B five* , *column C five*

So maybe en echo statement such as:

```
echo $i , " )" , " " , $inputA , " " , $inputB, " " , $inputC , "<br />";
```

I have been trying to read up on the `strpos()` and `for()` and `foreach()` on the PHP manual, but I am getting pretty much no where. Sorry to be long, wanted to paint a good picture

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> But I also need to echo also column_B and column_C along side the column_A.

You should name your input fields in a away that you get a more usable data structure in the first place.

You can append square brackets to get an array of input values in PHP - and you can specify indexes to use as well:

```
name="field[0][A]"
name="field[0][B]"

name="field[1][A]"
name="field[1][B]"
```

Try that, and then use `var_dump($_POST['field'])` to see what data structure you get from that.

Comment: you mean to add the square brackets in the <textarea name=""> HTML form, is that correct?

Comment: You don’t _need_ to, but if you do you will get are more consistent data structure that will be easier to handle.

Comment: Ok, I am with you. I am using five rows for testing.  Now that I have 5 arrays with nested arrays of 3 values, can you point out some statements or functions that I can use to apply a loop?  Example dump output: 'array(5) { [1]=> array(3) { ["A"]=> string(12) "321654987654" ["B"]=> string(1) "2" ["C"]=> string(3) "1.5" } [2]=> array(3) {  ...´

Comment: Two nested foreach loops should do to walk through a two-dimensional array.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$lt = range('A', 'C');
foreach ($_POST as $name => $input) {
    foreach ($lt as $i => $letter) {
        echo $i, " )";
        if (strpos($name, 'column_' . $letter) === 0) {
            if ($input !== '') {
                echo " ", $input;
            }
        }
        echo "<br />";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe like this ?

```
foreach($_POST as $name => $inputA) {
    $found = false;
    if(strpos($name, 'column_A')===0) {
        if($inputA !== ''){
            echo $i , " )" , " " , $inputA;
            $found = true;
        }
    }elseif(strpos($name, 'column_B')===0) {
        if($inputB !== ''){
            echo " " , $inputB;
            $found = true;
        }
    }elseif(strpos($name, 'column_C')===0) {
        if($inputC !== ''){
            echo " " , $inputC;
            $found = true;
        }
    }
    if($found){
        echo "<br />";
        $i++;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You mention you dont want to use `for` to loop trough each of the 150 rows, but I do think that is the best way to go. A loop with 150 iterations isnt a problem in this case.

The way you are going through the `POST` lets me know that you expect that the order of the `$_POST` array will be consistent with the order of the `FORM`. Now this will be true most of the time, but it's not guaranteed. So i'd advise against using it.

To make it work I would name the columns when creating the `FORM` with an identifier for the row so it will look something like

```
<form>
<!--row 1 -->
<textarea name='row_1_col_a'></textarea>
<textarea name='row_1_col_b'></textarea>
<textarea name='row_1_col_c'></textarea>

<!--row 2 -->
<textarea name='row_2_col_a'></textarea>
<textarea name='row_2_col_b'></textarea>
<textarea name='row_2_col_c'></textarea>

<!-- continue with all rows -->
</form>
```

You can easily do this with `PHP`

```
<form>

<?php
for($row=1;$row<=150;$row++) {
  ?>
  <!--row <?php echo $row; ?> -->
  <textarea name='row_<?php echo $row; ?>_col_a'></textarea>
  <textarea name='row_<?php echo $row; ?>_col_b'></textarea>
  <textarea name='row_<?php echo $row; ?>_col_c'></textarea>
  <?php
}
?>

</form>
```

Now you can uniquely identify each column on each row. In PHP You can then loop through the rows.

```
<?php
$completerows = 0;
for($row=1;$row<=150;$row++) {
  //check the vars for the row. If its empty continue with next row
  //I dont use the empty() method to check incase you need to enter a 0 in one of the columns

  //col A
  if (!isset($_POST['row_'.$row.'_col_a']) || strlen($_POST['row_'.$row.'_col_a'])==0)
    continue;
  $colA = $_POST['row_'.$row.'_col_a'];

  //col B
  if (!isset($_POST['row_'.$row.'_col_b']) || strlen($_POST['row_'.$row.'_col_b'])==0)
    continue;
  $colA = $_POST['row_'.$row.'_col_b'];

  //col C
  if (!isset($_POST['row_'.$row.'_col_c']) || strlen($_POST['row_'.$row.'_col_c'])==0)
    continue;
  $colA = $_POST['row_'.$row.'_col_c'];

  //if you are here the entire row is filled.
  //do something with $colA, $colB and $colC

  $completerows++;
}

var_dump($completerows);
?>
```

Comment: I am trying to work your answer, but something seems amiss. When I plug in the solution, I get only: `int(0)`. Ought there be some statement which assigns the `$completerows` to the `for() $rows` loop?

Comment: Now the completerows will only be incremented for the rows that have a value for col a, b and c. If one of them is missing it wont work. So make sure atleast one row has all the values posted